# Generics in scala for addition

Tags: scala, generics

```
class Calculator[A:Numeric]{

  var x:A = _;

  def sum() : A = x+x;  //error: 

}
```

compiler errors:

1. Can't resolve + symbol on A
2. Type mismatch; expected: String, actual: A

Answer (score 5):

```
class Calculator[A: Numeric]{ ... }
```

is syntax sugar for

```
class Calculator[A](implicit n: Numeric[A]){ ... }
```

If you look in [the docs for `Numeric`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) you'll find `implicit def mkOrderingOps` which uses the "Enrich my Library" pattern to add math operators like `+` to the `A` type.

You need to import `mkOrderingOps` from the instance of `Numeric`.

Keeping your current class signature, you can use `implicitly[Numeric[A]]` to get the instance. Putting it together, you get:

```
class Calculator[A: Numeric] {
  private val n = implicitly[Numeric[A]]
  import n._ // mkOrderingOps is included here     
  var a: A = _
  def sum = a + a // the + is coming from the mkOrderingOps conversion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the numeric ops:

```
  class Calculator[A : Numeric] {
    val numeric = implicitly[Numeric[A]]
    import numeric._

    var x: A = _
    def sum(): A = x + x
  }
```

which is equivalent to:

```
  class Calculator[A](implicit numeric: Numeric[A]) {
    import numeric._

    var x: A = _
    def sum(): A = x + x
  }
```